# React Component - Add custom functionality to npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, tags

I have an app which pretty much looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      tags: [
        { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
        { id: 2, name: "Pears" }
      ],
      suggestions: [
        { id: 3, name: "Bananas" },
        { id: 4, name: "Mangos" },
        { id: 5, name: "Lemons" },
        { id: 6, name: "Apricots" }
      ]
    }
  }

  handleDelete (i) {
    const tags = this.state.tags.slice(0)
    tags.splice(i, 1)
    this.setState({ tags })
  }

  handleAddition (tag) {
    const tags = [].concat(this.state.tags, tag)
    this.setState({ tags })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ReactTags
        tags={this.state.tags}
        suggestions={this.state.suggestions}
        handleDelete={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}
        handleAddition={this.handleAddition.bind(this)} />
    )
  }
}
```

It's based on [this npm module.](https://github.com/i-like-robots/react-tags)
I am not sure if I am missing something, but when I type in a tag, whilst I do see the suggestions pop up, I would also like to be able to press the `TAB` key and autocomplete the rest of the tag, whenever there is only one option left. Similar to the stackoverflow tag functionality.

My main question is this: How could I use a package like this, installed via npm, and extend its functionality? What would I do to make this my own, change things around etc.? I do not want to fiddle around in my npm modules folder!

Comment: Maybe you can fork it? Or make a pull request and get your changes merged?

Comment: Yes. you should fork it and use npm to install it directly from your github or publish your own npm module. npm install --save git+https://github.com/i-like-robots/react-tags.git

Comment: dont fork it, just wrap it in a component that handles what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the plugin and install it in your project as below

```
npm i {github_project_link}
```

If you want to contribute to the community. You can raise PR to the origin repo.